# Create an array of guidelines

Tags: inkscape

In many cases I would like to create an array of guidelines in Inkscape, but it is not clear how to do this. I have two main use cases:

(1) I want to fill an area with a specific number of guidelines. For example, I have a box and I want to divide it into 10 equal sections, so I need to create 9 equally spaced guidelines. In Sketchup this is done with the division operator (/) and an array, but how do you do it in Inkscape?

(2) I want to create guidelines some specific distance from each other. In other words, I want to create, say, 17 guidelines each spaced 1 inch apart. How do you do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Construct Grid path effect. I think this could solve both your use cases.

1. Draw a rectangle 25.4mm wide
2. Then in the Path Effects panel (Shift+CTRL+F7), add a new Path effect and choose Construct Grid.

Example

[image]

Then in the path effects panel, set X to 1, and Y to the number of segments required

[image]

These could be turned into actual guides by doing *Path > Object to Path*, and then *Object > Objects to guide*, if required.

Another possibly useful method is to use *Extensions > Render > Guides creator*. This can be used to create a bunch of guides all in one step.